# ElasticSearch: are there any modifying calls that use HTTP word GET?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

Are there any modifying operations that use HTTP word GET in Elastic Search? Or is it safe in a way to be able to access data without modifications while using HTTP GET request?

(Considering exposing a free form GET call to an index from internally accessible endpoint)

Answer (score 3):

No.

All calls that modify the data in some way use PUT or POST.   This is consistent with how the HTTP semantics were supposed to work.

There has been some pretty [significant normative text](https://httpwg.org/http-core/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics-latest.html#method.definitions) that has been written about this subject and for the most part I have seen Elasticsearch conform to that.   The same can't be said for all REST APIs that I have encountered.